# Why Scene (Action-Set) added to Hom e(HMHome) always have updated Characteristic's (HMCharacteristic) values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1, homekit

I am working on a demo iOS application based on HomeKit APIs.

I have created Scene (Actions-Set) AS1 for Particular Home (H1) with some services (S1 S2...) to perform multiple action in a go. I can create multiple scene without any problems, but I am facing problem in updating the any of created scene

Flow of my application:

- Show Added Home (ListView)
- Click on Any Home, detail screen appears with few Options (Accessory A1 ,Room A2  ,Scene A3....)
- Clicking on A1 Add the Accessory (can change the characteristic of added Accessory's service from here)
- A3 has a list of added Scene (Action-Set) as well a button to add new Scene (Action-Set) to current Home
- User can Click on any added Scene (ActionSet) to update its actions and name both

**Problem :** Once I changed the characteristic of services from Accessory A1 option then characteristics added to Scene's action gets updated to the same value.

**My assumption:** I was thinking each created Scene (Action-Set) maintain its own characteristics's value separately and if user modify characteristics of any service from accessory A1 (from somewhere else) then it should not affect the value of actions added to saved Scene (pre-condition - user picked that accessory in created Scene's action)

**My approach to update Action-Set (Scene) as,**

- Once user click on any added Action-Set services list appear where user can click on any services to updated its characteristic
- Access Actions of current Action-Set
- Access characteristic of each action (HMCharacteristicWriteAction)
  Access service of characteristic
- Create instance  of CustomServices (to keep track of some other info like user included that service to into current action set etc.)  and add it to Data-source and avoid repetition
- Once user done with value change and click on update actions button
- Start the Update process

**Update Scene (action-set)**

**1.Check if User changed the name of Action-set,**

- Then update the name of action set first, once success block executed delete all past added actions if exist.
- Add new actions to updated scene.

**2.If Scene (action-set) name is same as Old Name,**

- Delete all previous actions if exist.
- Add new actions to updated scene.

Here is the code snippet (prepare datasource) which is use to populate services listView

```
func prepareDataSource(){

var actionsArray = NSArray(array: 
self.currentScene!.actions.allObjects)
    
    for (var index = 0 ; index<actionsArray.count; index++ ){
        
        var sWritttenAction:HMCharacteristicWriteAction? = actionsArray[index] as? HMCharacteristicWriteAction
        
        if let sActionCharacteristic = sWritttenAction!.characteristic{
            
            var accessoryService = sActionCharacteristic.service as HMService
            
            if(!isServiceAlraedyAdded(accessoryService.name)){
                var sceneService = DMIAccessoryService.initWithService(accessoryService)
                sceneService.isSelected = true
                //Add Services
                self.services.append(sceneService)
                self.addedServices.append(sceneService)
                println("it's a different service")
            }
            else
            {
                println("Already has the same service")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have gone through the HomeKit documentation but found nothing related to this issue.

As far as I understand the action-set's concept it should maintained characteristics value separately so that we could change it's actions values later on.

I have already posted [this problem on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918567/why-action-set-added-to-home-always-have-services-with-current-updated-character). Now I am sure it is a bug in Apple Home api because once I try to re-execute the same action set( pre-condition: services characteristic's value changed by user from A1 option). It is executed successfully and update the all those accessories which have the same characteristics similar to created Scene (ActionSet).

Comment: I have Implemented scenes and trigger. It works perfectly fine. There is no issue in apple's api. Have you changed worl flow of scene? or Its same as you have describe above ?

Comment: Yeah everything works fine except updating scene (characteristics) @Samir

Comment: I have reviewed your workflow and found that the way its deal with update process is really wrong. Whats wrong ? 1st: Any actions must not be deleted except its done by user(Updating name of Actionset should not do that) 2st : Again it must not delete any actions. I will give you detailed answer to resolve this. Mostly by tommorw morning I will post it.

Comment: Ok , will be  waiting .... @Samir

Answer (score 1):

Scene can be created with **HMActionSet** object, 
 It expose only 3 apis i.e updateName(), addAction(), removeAction()

updateName can be used if user want to change name of scene. It should not call any other api (to removeAction or addAction)

**Add Action** 
addAction () is used to change the behavior of any Accessory using scene by using HMCharacteristic of Accessory. That characteristic must support **WriteAction** that can be check by.

```
[characteristic.properties containsObject:HMCharacteristicPropertyWritable]
```

**How to load characteristic** 
Characteristic can be displayed in Tableview or custom view can be created. And the value of that characteristic can be set to displayed view.

If current charcateristic is already added to actionset, we need to fetch the value from actionset objects's actions property.

```
- (void) readValueForCharacteristic:(HMCharacteristic *)characteristic completion:(void (^)(id, NSError *))completion {
for (HMCharacteristicWriteAction *action in self.actionSet.actions) {
    if ([characteristic isEqual:action.characteristic]) {
        completion([self getTargetValueForCharacteristic:characteristic],nil);
        return;
    }
}
[characteristic readValueWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completion(characteristic.value, error);
    });
}];
```

}

```
-(id) getTargetValueForCharacteristic:(HMCharacteristic *)characteristic {
id value;
for (HMCharacteristicWriteAction *action in self.actionSet.actions) {
    if ([action.characteristic isEqual:characteristic]) {
        value = action.targetValue;
    }
}
return value;
}
```

Now this value can be set on both while adding characteristic to scene or updating the characteristic.
As it checks that action is added to Scene ? then it will get value from actionSet. Else it will read current value of that chracteristic.

**Saving scene**
Same while adding Scene or updating scene. Just need to add a condition.

```
/** Create property */
@property (nonatomic) dispatch_group_t sceneGroup;
@property (nonatomic) NSError *error;

/** Initialize */
self.sceneGroup = dispatch_group_create();

- (void)saveActionSetWithName:(NSString *)name
            completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *error))completion {
    if (self.actionSet) {
        [self saveScene:self.actionSet];
        [self updateNameIfRequire:name];
    } else {
        [self createScene:name];
    }
    dispatch_group_notify(self.sceneGroup, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        completion(self.error);
        self.error = nil;
    });
}
```

If scene is already created then add Writable actions to actionset in saveScene: method. Also check if name of scene is changed and just change name using updateName: method if require.

If scene is not created, Create scene using HMHome class's method addActionSetWithName: by using home object, on its completion block call **saveScene** method and in that add writable actions to created scene.

You can take referance of [HMCatalog](http://bit.ly/HMCatalog) sample project by apple.
Its good if you create model custom class to manage Actionset.
Ask me if you have any query.